# Javascript/JQuery добавить class к каждому элементу внутри tr таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, table

Подскажите, как добавить для такой таблицы для каждого элемента `<tr class="tr_elem">` добавить класс `open`.
Но добавить только к рамках текущего `

Начал задумку как

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(this).parent().children('.tr_elem').toggle('normal').addClass('open');
  return false;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="top">
          <td class="click">Click 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr_elem">
          <td>some text 1</td>
          <td>some text 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr_elem">
          <td>some text 3</td>
          <td>some text 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="top">
          <td class="click">Click 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr_elem">
          <td>some text 5</td>
          <td>some text 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr_elem">
          <td>some text 7</td>
          <td>some text 8</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

То есть при нажатии на **Click 1** должны развернуться все элементы `tr` до следующего `class="click"`

Comment: Кажется, в вашем коду куда-то пропала одна строчка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, вам поможет [`nextUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) ?

```js
$(".click").click(function(){     
     
     $(this).closest(".top")
            .nextUntil(".top", ".tr_elem")
            .addClass("open");

  });
```

```css
.open td { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="top">
          <td class="click">Click 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr_elem">
          <td>some text 1</td>
          <td>some text 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr_elem">
          <td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr_elem">
          <td>some text 3</td><td>some text 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="top">
          <td class="click">Click 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr_elem">
          <td>some text 5</td>
          <td>some text 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr_elem">
          <td>some text 7</td>
          <td>some text 8</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @theblackpost дак там пока что и обработчики на `.click` не повешены.

Comment: @theblackpost вы либо `click` назначайте в конце документа, либо заверните в `$(function(){ ..... })` чтобы выполнялось после загрузки документа. лучше второй вариант

Comment: спасибо) Затупил) Подскажите, а реально сделать, чтобы при повторном нажатии блок сворачивался. То есть класс `.open` убирался?

Comment: @theblackpost `addClass` на `toggleClass` замените